# Rails - image_tag producing blank src in array of hashes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of hashes that look like this :

---

```
- :key: 180
  :value: http://*website*/profile_images/435814853748350976/jh2YLtFv_normal.png
- :key: 107
  :value: http://*website*/profile_images/3491950837/92d8d43c8fbf117275cbf44c2e29b19a_normal.png
- :key: 99
  :value: http://*website*/profile_images/3331461426/6285d0585ebabe52144158c4dccb5958_normal.png
- :key: 86
  :value: http://*website*/profile_images/2569456102/9orlmihu9vrnwkgmsgqa_normal.jpeg
- :key: 54
  :value: http://*website*/profile_images/378800000339609690/414596da6f84d6217ad19de1a649ad97_normal.jpeg
- :key: 42
  :value: http://*website*/profile_images/2402641590/5oya39hmpz4g82xl0f3v_normal.gif
```

I would like to iterate through this and display the images using the image_tag in Rails. However, when I try this using :

```
<%@array_of_hashes.each do |key,value|%>
  <%= image_tag(value, size: "40x40") %>
<% end %>
```

I get an output such as this :

```
<img height="30" src="" width="30">
```

Could someone please help me out? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use image_tag like this:

```
    <%@array_of_hashes.each do |key,value|%>
    <%= image_tag("#{value}", size: "40x40") %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work :( How would interpolating that have helped though?

Comment: You have to use quotes around the path: "#{}" will retain the quotes, try this `<%= image_tag("#{value}".html_safe, size: "40x40") %>`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either >_> I'm using Rails 4.0.1 by the way.

Comment: try to print and see that the 'value' `<%= value %>` actually exists ?

Comment: Looks like that is the issue. Trying `<%= value%>` gave no output, not in the source either. That just means that trying to access the "value" part in an array of hashes needs to be done in another way, but how?

Comment: Oh!! its an array of hashes so you should use it like this ....` <% @array_of_hashes.each do |hash|%>
    <%= image_tag("#{hash['value']}", size: "40x40") %>
    <% end %> `

Comment: Okay, your solution worked. Thank you so much. :D I would never have figured it out!